# QObject::connect in QRunnable - console

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I create simple multi threading server:

- Create server
- If new connection create new QThreadpool - QRunnable
- In runnable send message to client and wait request
- If client was been disconnected runnable write qDebug and runnable quit.

server.h

```
class Server : public QTcpServer
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0);
void StartServer();

protected:
void incomingConnection(int handle);

private:
QThreadPool *pool;
};
```

server.cpp:

```
#include "server.h"

Server::Server(QObject *parent) :
QTcpServer(parent)
{
pool = new QThreadPool(this);
pool->setMaxThreadCount(10);
}

void Server::StartServer()
{
this->listen(QHostAddress(dts.ipAddress),80));
}

void Server::incomingConnection(int handle)
{
Runnable *task = new Runnable();
task->setAutoDelete(true);

task->SocketDescriptor = handle;
pool->start(task);
}
```

runnable.h

```
class Runnable : public QRunnable
{
public:
Runnable();
int SocketDescriptor;

protected:
void run();

public slots:
void disconnectCln();
};
```

runnable.cpp

```
#include "runnable.h"

Runnable::Runnable()
{

}

void Runnable::run()
{
if(!SocketDescriptor) return;

QTcpSocket *newSocketCon = new QTcpSocket();
newSocketCon->setSocketDescriptor(SocketDescriptor);
```

**!!! How make it???!!!  QObgect::connect(newSocketCon, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOTS(disconnectCln()));**

```
newSocketCon->write(mes.toUtf8().data());
newSocketCon->flush();
newSocketCon->waitForBytesWritten();
}

void Runnable::disconnectCln()
{
qDebug() << "Client was disconnect";
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to have neglected to actually ask a question, but here's the immediate problem I spot with your code:  Your Runnable class does not inherit from QObject, and thus cannot have signals and slots.  You will need to do that to have any hope of making it work.

```
class Runnable : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Runnable();
  int SocketDescriptor;

protected:
  void run();

public slots:
  void disconnectCln();
};
```

There are two important things to note here.  1) if you use multiple inheritance, `QObject` must come first in the list.  2) To use signals and slots you must include the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class definition.